# i installed a dotclear blog & want to change template banner. how?

Tags: css, blogs, banner

ive had a TLD and an amazing paid host for the past 2 or 3 years now, and i use the softaculous script for instaling,so i wanted to turn my entire site from what it was for into a blog about a couple of specific things and i then got rid of my site, i installed word press first but i found it had far to many options which confused and overloaded me so i got rid of it,and instaled the blog that looked the most suitable for my needs-which was dotclear.

unfortunately for me,i cant even work out what to do to get an image in place of the sunflower photo/banner on the template. there are lots of css files to edit but i dont know which one to start with and what to put in.

i dont want to get rid of dotclear as its UI seems the most acessible and least overloading to me out of all the blog software ive got offered to me via softaculous,there support forum wont even let me join, it gives a error that says invalid captcha everytime.

im gessing the css will need editing rather than there being a direct button/setting as i cant find one anywhere-is anyoen able to direct me to what sort of .css folder i will probably need to be editing and what/where do i leave URL to the banner i hope to use?
im so sorry for asking such a beginer sounding question, im not lazy but id lost my entire memory for this and quite a few other tasks as well due to my severe epilepsy.i feel horible having to ask as i used to admin forums for people in the music industry.

thanks,cheers if you got this far.

---

i have googled threw many pages, i have gone threw the support files itself but struggled to understand what im doing,i have gone threw the oficial support forum and translated posts into english but cant register to ask questions because the captcha has a fault with it, i have swapped to other server software but found it to inacesible for my disabilitys. my support staff have also looked for me and have come up with no results.

Comment: To find which file sets that image you could use your browser devtools to inspect the banner. That should show which file is setting the image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.